# Why is bootstrap dropdown menu not working?

Tags: bootstrap-4

Here is my html template using bootstrap. But the dropdown menu is not working in chrome but it works in other platform such as codeplay.

Here is html code

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <h1 class="navbar-brand">Portfolio</h1>
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">About Me</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                   Projects
                   </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu bg-dark" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="">Another action</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: This is an issue with Javascript, you should put more code in your questions to see exactly where the problem is, make sure the browser loads the js files properly.

Comment: There are no js files only html css and bootstrap library

Comment: can you provide a link to the codeplay playground?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the bootstrap.js before your closing body tag.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/introduction/#quick-start

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <h1 class="navbar-brand">Portfolio</h1>
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">About Me</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                   Projects
                   </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu bg-dark" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="">Another action</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a JQuery CDN at the bottom of your file :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: try to put it in the <head></head> tag.